# AdvancedTomato can ping but cannot browse

Tags: networking, router, dns, internet-connection, tomato

Just moved and switched from comcast internet at my old place to verizon fios and tried to hook up my router (Netgear R6300v2 with Advanced Tomato firmware) to the ONT. I found I was able to ping but not browse common websites (google, yahoo, etc); this was found to be true on OSX and Windows laptops, as well on android phone when connected by WiFi. There is no packet loss with ping. I could browse parts of the verizon website (but not all - i.e. I couldn't browse to login to my account) .

Tried:

1. direct ethernet connection to the router (everything otherwise tested on WiFi) - no change
2. reset router NVRAM to default settings - no change
3. rebooted the ONT by unplugging (there is no battery) it for a minute - no change.
4. Directly entering the ip addresses into the browser - does not load the webpages either.
5. assigned DNS on router to 8.8.8.8 - no change
6. assigned DNS on Mac to 8.8.8.8 - no change
7. on the mac `telnet google.com 80 ; GET / HTTP/1.1` 
   gave a mess of html that looked like the google website with today's google doodle.
8. just waited overnight to see if things would magically correct themselves - no magic

No sure where to take this; it seems like it could be a DNS issue but I think one of my interventions would have corrected that by now. All my brains are used up and I don't want to start just making random changes to the configuration without some idea of what is going on.  Any help / thoughts / suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can ping, DNS is working fine. Please describe what exactly happens on the browser. Do you get a timeout error? Do you get a “domain unknown” error? Something else entirely?

Comment: It gives me a timeout error. I'm going to contact verizon and see if they can unlock the WAN MAC address.

Comment: Yes - I tried to upvote you but don't have enough reputation points. But thank you - this got it figured out.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verizon locks the account to the WAN mac address of the first router that receives DHCP from the ONT.

You can clone the mac address of the VZ router to the tomato WAN interface, or just call them and ask them to release the old routers mac address.

Depending on the speeds you are paying for you will want to make sure that the replacement router is capable of the max bandwidth limit with NAT enabled.

I should also note: when you use non-authorized equipment with VZ, you lose customer support for data services. They will tell you that they "do not support advanced routers".

Hope that clears it up for you.